# JQuery to collapse navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm completely new to HTML, CSS and Javascript. 
I have a navbar that when shown in mobile devices shows a button navbar-toggler. I need a little help with the Javascript for the onClick because I have never done it before and there was no real documentation about it on Bootstraps webpage.

Here's what it looks like on mobile devices:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="movielogo"><img src="moviefylogo.png" height="35px"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="library.html">Library</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="uploads.html">Uploads</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I need a little help with the Javascript for the onClick ==> `Bootstrap` will open and close nav. Check you attached bootstrap `jS`

Comment: what was the issue you have face and also which type of output you need...?

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, it's a built-in feature. Be sure you're including the js libraries correctly.

Comment: The output I need is for the menu to drop down and show my other items in my navbar. And then when the toggled-button is clicked again the menu would then again be hidden (as it is on the picture).

Comment: @JensO.AndersOlsén -- that is [exactly what you have working now](https://www.codeply.com/go/HbFJoLgbAi)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have included Jquery and Bootstrap CDN (CSS and JS) on your HTML file
It's working, check my jsfiddle link there : https://jsfiddle.net/u52vw4vs/1/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="movielogo"><img src="moviefylogo.png" height="35px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="library.html">Library</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="uploads.html">Uploads</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I just copy paste your code there on it, check "resource" on left menu, I added Bootstrap 4 CDN files.

Kind regards.